# love in an elevator

Tags: probability, statistics

The sign on the elevator in the Peters Building, which houses the School of Business and Economics at Wilfrid Laurier University, states, "Maximum Capacity 1,140 kilograms (2,500 pounds) or 16 Persons." A professor of statistics wonders what the probability is that 16 persons would weigh more than 1,140 kilograms. Suppose that the professor discovers that the weights of people who use the elevator are normally distributed with an average of 75 kilograms and a standard deviation of 10 kilograms. Calculate the probability that the professor seeks.

I understand what they are looking for, but I am having trouble setting this up, cant find the formula for this type of problem.

Comment: What's love got to do with it?

Comment: The sum of 16 normally-distributed random variables is itself a normally-distributed random variable.  You just need to find its mean and standard deviation. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche  Unless it's a freight elevator, those sixteen people had better like each other a fair bit...

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche What's love but a second-hand emotion?

Comment: If you've never believed in socks, have you ever believed in ANYTHING?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_{16}$ be the weights of 16 people. So these are likely independent and identically distributed $\mathcal{N}(75, 10^2)$. What does that mean about
$$
S_{16} = \sum_{k=1}^{16} X_k \text{ and } \mathbb{P}\left[S_{16} > 1140\right]?
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) to determine the mean and variance (the variance is the square of the standard deviation).  Using the notation from the Wikipedia article, we can change this to an average problem.  The average weight from 16 people weighing a total of 1,140 kg is 71.25 kg per person.  So if we take the average weight of the people on the elevator and ask when is the average weight greater than 71.25 we can answer the question:

\begin{align*}
\mu =&\ 75 \\
\sigma^2 =&\ \frac{\sigma_0^2}{n} \rightarrow \sigma = \frac{\sigma_0}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{10}{\sqrt{16}} = 2.5
\end{align*}

Now the problem is simple.  We have:

$S = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + ...}{n}$

Through the Central Limit Theorem we have showed that $S$ is *approximately* normally distributed with $\mu = 75$ and $\sigma = 2.5$.  We want to find the probability that the *average* weight is greater than 71.25 kg.  Consult any [table](http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATS7/ZChart.htm) and find the proper z-score:

\begin{align*}
z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma} = \frac{71.25 - 75}{2.5} = -1.5
\end{align*}

Now consult the table to find that $p(z < -1.5) \approx 0.0668$ $\leftarrow$ ***make sure you know what kind of table you are looking at!***  This means the probability that $z > -1.5$ is the compliment of this:

\begin{align*}
p(z >-1.5) = 1 - p(z < -1.5) \approx 1.0 - 0.0668 = 0.9332 \approx 93.3\%
\end{align*}

Comment: Possibly simpler: combined weight of 16 people averages 1200kg with a standard deviation of 40kg (variance increases linearly with the number of people, so standard deviation increases with the square root of the number of people). As noted above, the chance this exceeds 1140kg is the chance the standard normal variable exceeds -1.5 standard deviations, or about 0.9332 as noted above